# Test actual class method using mock object in PHPUnit

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

What I want to do: create a Mock object that does not execute the `__constructor()`, but DOES have all methods as they were coded (not mocked to return null).

[The docs](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html) say:

> "By default, all methods of the original class are replaced with a
>   dummy implementation that just returns null (without calling the
>   original method). Using the `will($this->returnValue())` method, for
>   instance, you can configure these dummy implementations to return a
>   value when called."

That's not what I want. I don't want to force a method to return a known value. I want to test the method itself, and therefore need a functioning instantiation of the class, but with a disabled constructor.

How do I do that?

Comment: This really begs the question: Why do you NOT want to execute the constructor? Normally this would be only function you absolutely must execute as written, in order to properly set up object to test the class. Mock objects are used for the dependencies of said class, in order to be able to properly test it without involving third party systems or other business code.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote test cases for the class itself to return data given the parameters required, without using Mocks.  Mocks are for external references to this class, that need to know that function Bar() returns Foo, so your class waiting on that response processes the results correctly.

Given this very simply PHP class:

```
<?php
class CATEGORY_SCOPE
{
    public $CategoryName;
    public $CategoryNo;

    function __construct($CategoryNo = NULL, $CategoryName = NULL)
    {
        $this->CategoryName = $CategoryName;
        $this->CategoryNo   = $CategoryNo;
    }

    protected function SetCategoryName($Name)
    {
        $this->CategoryName = Name;
    }
}
?>
```

I would then test it:

```
<?php
require_once(substr(__FILE__, 0, -5));  // strip '.test' extension
class TEST_CATEGORY_SCOPE extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    protected function setUp()
    {
    }

    public function testObjectCreation()
    {
        $CategoryInfo = new CATEGORY_SCOPE();
        $this->assertInstanceOf('CATEGORY_SCOPE', $CategoryInfo);
    }

    public function testConstructFieldOrder()
    {
        $CategoryInfo = new CATEGORY_SCOPE(1500, 'Category Name');
        $this->assertEquals(1500, $CategoryInfo->CategoryNo);
        $this->assertEquals('Category Name', $CategoryInfo->CategoryName);
    }

    public function testConstructDefaults()
    {
        $CategoryInfo = new CATEGORY_SCOPE();
        $this->assertNull($CategoryInfo->CategoryNo);
        $this->assertNull($CategoryInfo->CategoryName);
    }

    public function testSetCategoryName()
    {
        $CategoryInfo = new CATEGORY_SCOPE();
        $CategoryInfo->SetCategoryName('New Name');
        $this->assertEquals('New Name', $CategoryInfo->CategoryName);
    }
}
?>
```

This will have tested that the class itself works, and I can set certain values. Obviously this is a simple example. Now, when something uses this class, I can still directory test the field settings, but that is covered here.

To your question then, lets assume I have class FOO() that accepts CATEGORY_SCOPE as a parameter in the constructor. You would mock the CATEGORY_SCOPE class, and set the internal Bar() function to return some data regardless of the processing the CATEGORY_SCOPE class does.

```
<?php
class FOO
{
    public $ReturnValue
    function __construct($CategoryScope)
    {
        $this->ReturnValue = $CategoryScope->Bar();
    }
}
?>
```

By mocking the CATEGORY_SCOPE class so the Bar() function always returns 5 (some value that makes sense to your code), you can then test that the FOO class works as expected.

```
<?php
require_once(substr(__FILE__, 0, -5));  // strip '.test' extension
class TEST_FOO extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    protected function setUp()
    {
    }

    public function testObjectCreation()
    {
        $FooInfo = new FOO();
        $this->assertInstanceOf('FOO', $FooInfo);
    }

    public function testFoo()
    {
        // Set Up the Mock so Bar() returns 5 using your mock library

        ... <- Actual code for the mock goes here

        $FooInfo = new FOO($CategoryMock);
        $this->assertEquals(5, $FooInfo->Bar());
    }
}
?>
```